# Sql to count m and f based on age

Tags: sql

i have sql table like this

table name: person

| age | gander |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | m |
| 21 | m |
| 21 | f |
| 22 | m |
| 22 | f |

what is query to get output like this:

| age | count_m | count_f |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 2 | 1 |
| 22 | 1 | 1 |

i want to count m and f based on age

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might want to include that,

Comment: Which DBMS? If you hover over or tap the SQL tag, which you selected, it instructs you to specify.

Comment: I guess the best answer for SQL questions that fail to disclose the most basic information (RDBMS and version) consists of two votes: down & close. Unless it's explicitly about standard SQL, of course.) That aside, a column named `age` is typically broken design. Should be birthday (or -year) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of conditional aggregation will do the trick.

```
select age
, count(case when gander = 'm' then 1 end) as count_m
, count(case when gander = 'f' then 1 end) as count_f
from person
group by age
order by age
```

Comment: So... you answered a question where the OP hasn't shown any work (no SQL, no output issues, no errors, nothing), nor have the even shared which SQL database they're using. Best not to answer questions like this (maybe you just solved their homework for them?). This was their very first contribution here; might be better to offer guidance on how to improve their question (as the other comments have done).